# Temando Critical Error Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, shipping, temando

Since my store has been updated to latest `Magento 2.3.3` when I go to product page I got this error.

> temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again.

I have tried `Setup:Update`, `Di:Compile` and a lot of other similar things to get this working but of no use.
I don't want to disable this module as I need it.
So anyone have any solution please put it here.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: not yet even I have asked it on Magento Community and its been more than 2 weeks but nothing @WillWright

Answer (score 0):

To complete solve this you will need to disable the Termando module **and** delete their attributes (starting with ts_) ... not great but thats all we have this far

Comment: and the attributes are created as system so delete needs to be programmatic or first change that system flag in database

Answer (score 0):

To remove the error without disabling the module remove source_model 
 of attribute_code ts_packaging_id

via sql

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `source_model` = null WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'ts_packaging_id';
```

or via an UpgradeSchema.php (replace namespace and increment module version in module.xml)

```
class UpgradeSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface{
/**
 * Eav setup factory
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function upgrade(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $id = $eavSetup->getAttributeId(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'ts_packaging_id'
        );
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $id,
            'source_model',
            null
        );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is a temporary solution and amazingly I just told it today to someone on gitHub.

Comment: As far as I remember this solution just show up the attributes but does not remove the error.

Comment: For sure it's temporary solution until I hope magento fix it on 2.3.4 but it remove completely all errors from Temando for me, I tried it this morning

Comment: Good to know :-)

Comment: if you disable the module you get other errors, price and product export errors due to the class information hidden in the attributes. On the other hand the attributes cannot be deleted in admin either.